# Generate data for MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, data-generation

Is there a program like Red Gate's [Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/) for MS SQL Server that generates data based on your database schema for MySQL?

Other alternatives (easy) to accomplish the objective very much welcomed!

Answer (score 3):

Check out benerator:

http://databene.org/databene-benerator

Answer (score 0):

Look at generatedata, which is available via http://www.generatedata.com

You can also fork the project: https://github.com/benkeen/generatedata

It's pretty simple and I didn't need a manual to figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a small script which can generate & populate your DB, it also can execute SQL files. Everything in synchronized manner (important if you have relationships defined in your DB)

Works like a charm for our team.

https://github.com/blacktea/populate-db-now